# Visual studio 2010 with win 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, 64-bit

i installed x86 iso found in msdn for VS2010 ultimate on my win 7 64 bit. when i try to launch the IDE it gives methe following error

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). click ok to close the application
the title of the popup is devenv.exe
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/0c6eac91-7bdd-4933-a79e-602564d3be67

Comment: yes, but this user was able to open VS2010 but his dll was not working. for me the Vs2010 itself won't start.

Comment: Any reason you can't run the 64 bit version?

Comment: i don;t see a download for 64 bit vs2010 ultimate

Comment: That's strange - I wouldn't that that the bit-depth of the edition would be limited by your MSDN subscription level.

Comment: i have installed this on a different win 7 64bit machine and it works there, not sure why this one is causing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to install C++ as as part of VS to get it to work

Comment: is this because of a missing C++ runtime, maybe?